# Pandas how to flag rows between a start (1) and multiple ends (2 or 3)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, signals

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['Date'] = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05',
              '2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
              '2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15',
              '2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20']
df['Machine'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A']
df['Signal'] = [0,1,2,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,1]
df['Status'] =  0
```

And the following function which generates a 'Status' column for the machine A. In the Signal col, 1 switches the machine on (Status col 1) which remains 1 until the machine receives either 2 or 3 which are signals to switch the machine status to 0 (off) until the machine receives Signal 1 again.

I've solved the issue of maintaining the previous Status row value of 1 or 0 with the below function:

```
def s_gen(dataset, Signal):
    _status = 0
    status0 = []
    for (i) in Signal:
        if _status == 0:
            if i == 1:
                _status = 1 
        elif _status == 1:
            if (i == 2 or i==3):
                _status = 0
        status0.append(_status)
        
    dataset['status0'] = status0

    return dataset['status0']

df['Status'] = s_gen(df,df['Signal'])
df.drop('status0',axis=1,inplace = True)
df
```

This appends the newly created column to the dataframe. However I have a larger dataframe with many different values in the Machine column (grouped as series; A,A,A,B,B,B etc) and the results of the function cannot overlap. Using groupby didn't work. So I think the next step is to produce each sequence of 'Status' as a separate list and concatenate them before appending the whole series to the larger dataframe as part of a larger outer loop.

This is the desired outcome:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['Date'] = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05',
              '2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
              '2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15',
              '2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20',
              '2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05',
              '2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
              '2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15',
              '2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20']

df['Machine'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
                'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B',]
df['Signal'] = [0,1,2,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,1]
df['Status'] = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]
df
```

What I'm struggling with is, if the function processes each machine's data separately then appends it to the dataframe, it would have to loop through each machine, then concatenate all the Status series produced, then append that larger series to the dataframe.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
dfList = df[df['Machine']]
dfListU = pd.DataFrame([])
dfListU = dfList['Machine'].unique()
dfListU.flatten()

def s_gen2(item, dataset, Signal):
   
    data = df[df.Machine==m]
    for m in dfListU:
        _status = 0
        status0 = []

        for (i) in Signal:
            if _status == 0:
                if i == 1:
                    _status = 1 
            elif _status == 1:
                if (i == 2 or i==3):
                    _status = 0
            #status0.append(_status)

        dataset['status0'] = status0

        return dataset['status0']
    for i in dfListU:
        df1 = pd.concat(i)
    status0.append(_status)
df['Status'] = s_gen(df,df['Signal'])
df.drop('status0',axis=1,inplace = True)
df
```

Which results in the error - KeyError: "None of [Index(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',\n       'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',\n       'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Is is better to loop the function through the dfListU (list of unique machines) then concatenate the outcome? I've tried to avoid using loops but couldn't find any other way to compare the previous status row with the same row in the Signal column.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach would be to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the known statuses, then to [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) them:

```
df['Status'] = (df['Signal']
 .map({1:1, 2:0, 3:0})
 .groupby(df['Machine']).ffill()
 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 )
```

Output:

```
          Date Machine  Signal  Status
0   2020-01-01       A       0       0
1   2020-01-02       A       1       1
2   2020-01-03       A       2       0
3   2020-01-04       A       0       0
4   2020-01-05       A       1       1
5   2020-01-06       A       3       0
6   2020-01-07       A       0       0
7   2020-01-08       A       0       0
8   2020-01-09       A       0       0
9   2020-01-10       A       3       0
10  2020-01-11       A       0       0
11  2020-01-12       A       1       1
12  2020-01-13       A       0       1
13  2020-01-14       A       0       1
14  2020-01-15       A       3       0
15  2020-01-16       A       0       0
16  2020-01-17       A       1       1
17  2020-01-18       A       0       1
18  2020-01-19       A       0       1
19  2020-01-20       A       1       1
20  2020-01-01       B       0       0
21  2020-01-02       B       1       1
22  2020-01-03       B       2       0
23  2020-01-04       B       0       0
24  2020-01-05       B       1       1
25  2020-01-06       B       3       0
26  2020-01-07       B       0       0
27  2020-01-08       B       0       0
28  2020-01-09       B       0       0
29  2020-01-10       B       3       0
30  2020-01-11       B       0       0
31  2020-01-12       B       1       1
32  2020-01-13       B       0       1
33  2020-01-14       B       0       1
34  2020-01-15       B       3       0
35  2020-01-16       B       0       0
36  2020-01-17       B       1       1
37  2020-01-18       B       0       1
38  2020-01-19       B       0       1
39  2020-01-20       B       1       1
```

Comment: Should have known you'd come up with the simplest solution! :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way. Use the cumsum function to mark distinct sets of rows/blocks that start with the 2/3 condition. Then Mask the signal values which are not 1 then group the masked column by Machine and blocks and forward fill the values.

```
m1 = df['Signal'].ne(1)
m2 = df['Signal'].isin([2, 3])

df['Status'] = df['Signal'].mask(m1).groupby([df['Machine'], m2.cumsum()]).ffill().fillna(0)
```

---

```
          Date Machine  Signal  Status
0   2020-01-01       A       0     0.0
1   2020-01-02       A       1     1.0
2   2020-01-03       A       2     0.0
3   2020-01-04       A       0     0.0
4   2020-01-05       A       1     1.0
5   2020-01-06       A       3     0.0
6   2020-01-07       A       0     0.0
7   2020-01-08       A       0     0.0
8   2020-01-09       A       0     0.0
9   2020-01-10       A       3     0.0
10  2020-01-11       A       0     0.0
11  2020-01-12       A       1     1.0
12  2020-01-13       A       0     1.0
13  2020-01-14       A       0     1.0
14  2020-01-15       A       3     0.0
15  2020-01-16       A       0     0.0
16  2020-01-17       A       1     1.0
17  2020-01-18       A       0     1.0
18  2020-01-19       A       0     1.0
19  2020-01-20       A       1     1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as a state machine and use vectorized code:

```
import numpy as np

conds = [df['Signal'].eq(1), df['Signal'].isin([2, 3])]
vals = [1, 0]

# np.nan for df['Signal'] == 0 (default parameter)
status = pd.Series(np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=vals, default=np.nan))

# fill forward the current status then fill remain values with 0
df['Status'] = status.groupby(df['Machine']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          Date Machine  Signal  Status
0   2020-01-01       A       0       0
1   2020-01-02       A       1       1
2   2020-01-03       A       2       0
3   2020-01-04       A       0       0
4   2020-01-05       A       1       1
5   2020-01-06       A       3       0
6   2020-01-07       A       0       0
7   2020-01-08       A       0       0
8   2020-01-09       A       0       0
9   2020-01-10       A       3       0
10  2020-01-11       A       0       0
11  2020-01-12       A       1       1
12  2020-01-13       A       0       1
13  2020-01-14       A       0       1
14  2020-01-15       A       3       0
15  2020-01-16       A       0       0
16  2020-01-17       A       1       1
17  2020-01-18       A       0       1
18  2020-01-19       A       0       1
19  2020-01-20       A       1       1
20  2020-01-01       B       0       0
21  2020-01-02       B       1       1
22  2020-01-03       B       2       0
23  2020-01-04       B       0       0
24  2020-01-05       B       1       1
25  2020-01-06       B       3       0
26  2020-01-07       B       0       0
27  2020-01-08       B       0       0
28  2020-01-09       B       0       0
29  2020-01-10       B       3       0
30  2020-01-11       B       0       0
31  2020-01-12       B       1       1
32  2020-01-13       B       0       1
33  2020-01-14       B       0       1
34  2020-01-15       B       3       0
35  2020-01-16       B       0       0
36  2020-01-17       B       1       1
37  2020-01-18       B       0       1
38  2020-01-19       B       0       1
39  2020-01-20       B       1       1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some confusing lines in s_gen2 block. I suspect it wouldn't compile. For example, in below lines, m is used before assignment.

```
data = df[df.Machine==m]
for m in dfListU:
```

Anyway, now that your machine list is grouped, s_gen is quite reusable with a tweak to leave the dataframe unchanged.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['Date'] = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05',
            '2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
            '2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15',
            '2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20',
            '2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05',
            '2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10',
            '2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15',
            '2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20']

df['Machine'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B',]
df['Signal'] = [0,1,2,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,1] 

def s_gen(Signal):
    _status = 0
    status0 = []
    for (i) in Signal:
        if _status == 0:
            if i == 1:
                _status = 1 
        elif _status == 1:
            if (i == 2 or i==3):
                _status = 0
        status0.append(_status)

    return status0

unique_machines = df['Machine'].unique()

whole_status_list = []

for m in unique_machines:
    data = df[df.Machine==m]

    whole_status_list.extend(s_gen(data["Signal"]))

df["Status"] = whole_status_list
```

The code above shall be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your `s_gen` function as it only needs to know whether to turn off/on the machine:

```py
def s_gen(Signal):
    _status = 0
    Status = []
    for sig in Signal:
        _status = 1 if sig == 1 else 0 if sig in [2, 3] else _status
        Status.append(_status)
    return Status
```

You can then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the status on a per-machine basis:

```py
df['NewStatus'] = df.groupby('Machine')['Signal'].transform(s_gen)
```

For your sample data, we can then check correctness:

```py
(df['Status'] == df['NewStatus']).all()
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` to split the dataframe to different groups based on **"Machine"** key, then use `transform` to apply your function to **"Signal"** column of each group. Please note that I have modified your `s_gen` function to be suitable for transform operation.

```
def s_gen(signal):
    _status = 0
    status0 = []
    for (i) in signal:
        if _status == 0:
            if i == 1:
                _status = 1
        elif _status == 1:
            if i == 2 or i == 3:
                _status = 0
        status0.append(_status)

    return status0

df['Status'] = df.groupby('Machine')['Signal'].transform(s_gen)
```

If you want to be utilize vectorization to speed up your process, you can use the following transformation:

```
# divide dataframe into groups based on "Machine" key
machine_groups = df.groupby("Machine")

# find out when the signal is switched (signal != 0)
df['SignalSwitch'] = (machine_groups.Signal.diff().fillna(machine_groups.Signal.transform('first')).astype(bool) & (df['Signal'] != 0))

# initialize 'Status' column
df['Status'] = None

# fill the 'Status' column with 1 if signal is 1 at the time of 'SignalSwitch', 0 if signal is 0
df.loc[df['SignalSwitch'] & (df['Signal'] == 1), 'Status'] = 1
df.loc[df['SignalSwitch'] & (df['Signal'].isin([2, 3])), 'Status'] = 0

# forward fill the remaining timestamps with previous status, fill NA (for cases when dataframe starts with signal = 0)
df['Status'] = machine_groups.Status.ffill().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. Brilliant. Kicking myself because I didn't realize those simple changes.